# How can I print the current view and exlude master layout in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, printing

Is there a way to print the current rendered view only, excluding the master layout around it?
I'm generating a report and want to print this, but want to exclude all but the report (Report.cshtml) itself. I figure javascript can launch the print dialog, but this gives me the entire page. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you alter the master layout to use css with `@media print` to not print the master elements?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you mean by that? In that context, perhaps I should mention that I use Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set to view this:

```
@{
   Layout = null; //or set url to another master layout
}
```